# how to remove first and last letter from string

Tags: python-3.x

heres the question:
Remove First and Last Character
It's pretty straightforward. Your goal is to create a function that removes the first and last characters of a string. You're given one parameter, the original string. You don't have to worry with strings with less than two characters.

i have no idea how to do it because of the fact that it wants me to remove first and last letter and not the first and last word

Comment: How would you remove the first and last word?

Comment: list1.pop() and then do list1.pop(0)

Comment: So are you given a list of strings? For example ["I", "love", "stack", "overflow"] and want to remove the first and last character of each string in the list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Slicing is the best way to go about that.

```
test_string = 'This is a test!'
print (test_string [1:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

From your response that removing the first and last word would be done by list1.pop() and list1.pop(0) I am assuming that you are given a list of strings and are required to remove the first and last character of each string in the list.

If my assumption is correct you can do a combination of slicing and list comprehension.

```
list_of_str = ["words", "words", "words", "words"]
list_of_shortened_str = [word[1:-1] for word in list_of_str]
# list_of_shortened_str = ["ord", "ord", "ord", "ord"]
```